# What is the underlying structure of std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, initializer-list

**First part :**

`std::initializer_list` is a really helpful feature of C++11, so I wondered how it is implemented in the standard library. From what I read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/), the compiler creates an array of type `T` and gives the pointer to the `initializer_list<T>`.

It also states that copying an `initializer_list` will create a new object referencing the same data : why is it so ? I would have guessed that it either :

- copies the data for the new `initializer_list`
- moves ownership of the data to the new `initializer_list`

**Second part :**

From just one of many online references for the `std::vector` constructors:

```
vector (initializer_list<value_type> il,
    const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

> **(6) initializer list constructor**
>
> Constructs a container with a copy of each of the elements in *il*, in the same order.

I am not comfortable with move semantics yet, but couldn't the data of `il` be moved to the `vector` ? I am not aware of the deep implementation of `std::vector` but IIRC it uses plain-old arrays.

Comment: Seems like another reason not to trust cplusplus.com. Delving into the standard, one eventually arrives at the initialiser-list ctor calling the pair-of-iterators ctor, which (using emplace construction) will move the elements if possible.

Comment: cplusplus.com is a terrible, terrible site that does harm to the C++ community. Someone should smash the servers hosting it, burn the hard drives, encase them in concrete and sink them to the bottom of the ocean.

Comment: `What is the underlying structure of std::initializer_list?` Abstracted away from you, for good reason.

Comment: I was not referring to cplusplus.com as **the** reference (Bible), but I thought it was just an online edition of the standard. Thanks for warning about though, what flaws makes it "terrible" ?

Comment: @Angew I don't like having to defend that site, but it is correct in this case. `initializer_list` only provides read access to its elements.

Comment: @tehinternetsismadeofcatz I haven't perused it since a recent overhaul, but it used to have several errors and code examples that were either actually wrong or suggested bad ideas. I can't speak for the current content; nowadays I use a standard draft or cppreference.com (which is a wiki, so mistakes can be caught and fixed by the community) as my reference.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Ah, my bad. Thanks for correcting me. Seeing as I'm stuck with VS2010's version of C++11 for now, I haven't studied ILs in enough detail to be aware of this.

Comment: Good question, I still don't see a satisfactory answer. To me, so far, it looks like `std::initializer_list` is a language feature and the `std::` part is misleading to make you think it is a library feature. Even looking at the code of initializer_list there is something strange about it that makes it a special object it seems. In fact in the GCC STL there is a comment that reads: `      // The compiler can call a private constructor.` This reinforces my belief that it is not a normal class. If this is true, I wonder if one can specialize it or extend it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What is the underlying structure of `std::initializer_list`?

Most likely, just a pair of pointers, or a pointer and a size. Paragraph 18.9/2 of the C++11 Standard even mentions this in a (non-normative) note:

> An object of type `initializer_list<E>` provides access to an array of objects of type `const E`. [ Note:
>   **A pair of pointers or a pointer plus a length would be obvious representations for `initializer_list`**.
>   `initializer_list` is used to implement initializer lists as specified in 8.5.4. Copying an `initializer list` does
>   not copy the underlying elements. —end note ]

Moreover:

> I am not comfortable with move semantics yet, but couldn't the data of `il` be moved to the vector?

**No**, you can't move from the elements of an `initializer_list`, since elements of an `initializer_list` are supposed to be immutable (see the first sentence of the paragraph quoted above). That's also the reason why only `const`-qualified member functions give you access to the elements.

Comment: Do note that technically a constructor such as `foo(foo const&&);` is a move constructor, and would in fact be called if you wrapped the iterators of an `std::initializer_list` in `std::move_iterator`s or used some such trickery. Such a constructor can rarely do anything useful (or different from what a standard *copy* constructor can do) though.

Comment: @LucDanton: `foo(foo const&&)`... ew... :) But yes, technically you're correct. Still doesn't change the fact that elements of an `initializer_list` are meant to be immutable, so that "move constructor" won't be allowed to move anything without causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @AndyProwl: An initializer list can also contain variable references. In that case a move ctor moves the data of the referred element. So yes, the list itself is immutable (will always contain the same reference), but the move ctor can be useful.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: Strictly speaking, it cannot contain references, although it can contain `reference_wrapper`s. Then you would have to do: `foo x(std::move(static_cast<foo&>(*l.begin())));`, which is getting contrived.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Yes, very contrived. They are clearly not designed to work that way... The problem is that `const` is not transitive as the `std::immutable` concept should be (but not standard yet: see D as an example of language where these two things are well given distinct keywords). This gives this *workarounds* some (sort of ) citizenship. Good point.