# std::vector init with braces call copy constructor twice

Tags: c++, stdvector, curly-braces, list-initialization

Why when I init std::vector with braces

```
std::vector<TS> vec {ts1, ts2};
```

Compiler call twice copy constructor operator? On the other hand - with push_back it called only once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct TS{
    TS(){
        cout<<"default constructor\n";
    }

    TS(const TS &other) {
        cout<<"Copy constructor\n";
    }

    TS(TS &&other) noexcept{
        cout<<"Move constructor\n";
    }

    TS& operator=(TS const& other)
    {
        cout<<"Copy assigment\n";
        return *this;
    }

    TS& operator=(TS const&& other) noexcept
    {
        cout<<"Move assigment\n";
        return *this;
    }

    ~TS(){
        cout<<"destructor\n";
    }

};

int main() {
    TS ts1;
    TS ts2;
    cout<<"-----------------------------------------\n";
    std::vector<TS> vec {ts1, ts2};
    //vec.push_back(ts1);
    //vec = {ts1, ts2};
    cout<<"-----------------------------------------\n";



    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/qcPG7X

Comment: No assignment operator should be called with brace-init, but the arguments are copied into the `std::initializer_list<TS>` and copied out => two copy-constructor calls per argument. You can move them into the `initializer_list` (`std::vector<TS> vec {std::move(ts1), std::move(ts2)};`) but you cannot move them out, so at least one copy-constructor call is necessary.

Comment: Can I, at least force it somehow to use move assigment, instead of cope?

Comment: Not with list-initialization. You can however write a workarounds, for example a function that returns a type that stores the arguments of the function as references, and which provides a conversion to a `std::vector`, called à la `vector<TS> vec( collect_references(ts1, ts2) );`.

Comment: @DyP function should return std::vector. Ok, good idea, thank you.

Comment: No, because it wouldn't now what `value_type`. It should return a type with a `template<class T> operator std::vector<T>() const` to *deduce* the `value_type` *for* the vector to be initialized; it then can use `emplace_back` and avoid *any* copy-ctor, if possible. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8d158d2b0bb0d5d)

Comment: Oops, I forgot to `std::forward` appropriately ;) [Fixed live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/429e8fc820ecedc3)

Comment: @DyP What does this means auto collect_references(Ts&&... pp) -> reference_collector<Ts&&...> just type deduction? And you make "new" with this "std::forward<Ts>(pp)" ? Honestly, a little bit complicate to me.

Comment: `auto function_name(parameter_list) -> return_type` is just another way to write `return_type function_name(parameter_list)` (where you can use the parameter names in the return type); the `Ts&&...` here declares a function parameter pack, where each parameter is a "universal reference". I agree that it's complicated, but it should be invisible to the user of `collect_references`. Each argument you pass is just forwarded to a `vec.emplace_back` call without any conversion, copying or moving.

Comment: But to avoid copying we should do std::move on each argument of collect_references?

Comment: As can be seen in my fixed example, you *can* use a `std::move` to store an rvalue reference in the reference collector; the argument will then be moved exactly once (into the `vector`) and never copied. If you pass an lvalue, the argument will be copied exactly once (into the `vector`).

Comment: I mean move std::move to the function/template/whatever body. That make it more readable. But this is seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, `initializer_list`s pass everything by const-reference. It is probably not safe to `move` from one. The `initializer_list` constructor of a `vector` will copy each of the elements.

Here are some links:
[initializer_list and move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193102/initializer-list-and-move-semantics)

> No, that won't work as intended; you will still get copies. I'm pretty
>   surprised by this, as I'd thought that initializer_list existed to
>   keep an array of temporaries until they were move'd.
>
> begin and end for initializer_list return const T *, so the result of
>   move in your code is T const && — an immutable rvalue reference. Such
>   an expression can't meaningfully be moved from. It will bind to an
>   function parameter of type T const & because rvalues do bind to const
>   lvalue references, and you will still see copy semantics.

[Is it safe to move elements of a initializer list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957166/is-it-safe-to-move-elements-of-a-initializer-list?rq=1)

> initializer_list only provides const access to its elements. You could
>   use const_cast to make that code compile, but then the moves might end
>   up with undefined behaviour (if the elements of the initializer_list
>   are truly const). So, no it is not safe to do this moving. There are
>   workarounds for this, if you truly need it.

[Can I list-initialize a vector of move-only type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type?rq=1)

> The synopsis of  in 18.9 makes it reasonably clear
>   that elements of an initializer list are always passed via
>   const-reference. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be any way of
>   using move-semantic in initializer list elements in the current
>   revision of the language.

[questions regarding the design of std::initializer_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623098/questions-regarding-the-design-of-stdinitializer-list/17623839#17623839)

> From section 18.9 of the C++ Standard:
>
> An object of type initializer_list provides access to an array of objects of type const E. [ Note: A pair of pointers or a pointer plus
>   a length would be obvious representations for initializer_list.
>   initializer_list is used to implement initializer lists as specified
>   in 8.5.4. Copying an initializer list does not copy the underlying
>   elements. — end note ]
>
> I think the reason for most of these things is that
>   std::initializer_list isn't actually a container. It doesn't have
>   value semantics, it has pointer semantics. Which is made obvious by
>   the last portion of the quote: Copying an initializer list does not
>   copy the underlying elements. Seeing as they were intended solely for
>   the purpose of initializing things, I don't think it's that surprising
>   that you don't get all the niceties of more robust containers such as
>   tuples.

<strike>If I understand the last part correctly, it means that two sets of copies are needed since `initializer_list` does not copy the underlying elements.</strike> (The previous quote is only relevant if you attempt to use an `initializer_list` without copying out the elements.)

[What is the underlying structure of std::initializer_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894566/what-is-the-underlying-structure-of-stdinitializer-list)

> No, you can't move from the elements of an initializer_list, since
>   elements of an initializer_list are supposed to be immutable (see the
>   first sentence of the paragraph quoted above). That's also the reason
>   why only const-qualified member functions give you access to the
>   elements.

---

If you want, you can use `emplace_back`:

```
vec.emplace_back(TS());
vec.emplace_back(TS());
vec.push_back(std::move(ts1));
vec.push_back(std::move(ts2));
```

Comment: I can use emplace_back, indeed. But with {} - it looks much beautifull.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have two elements there.

Comment: The copy-ctor will be called *twice* for each argument, so four times in total for the two arguments.

Comment: Poorly stated question, then

Comment: The OP even says "copy assignment operator" ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have provided, with Microsoft compiler, the copy constructor for TS when it is in the vector initializer list will be called only once!

```
TS ts1;  // contructor called
std::vector<TS> vec {ts1};  // copy constructor called. Only once.
```

If you create an object in the initializer list, it will do both:

```
std::vector<TS> vec {TS()}; // constructor, then copy constructor called
```

In the second case, if you have a number of objects, all constructors will be called first, then all copy contructors.